# What is the shortcut to allow new lines in linux terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal, command, shortcut

I'm searching for the couple of shortcuts to allow to write multilines commands in the terminal.
I know it exist, I used it many times, but I can't remberber them, and I don't find them in google...

The behavior it have:
Once in the middle of a line, it will "delete" the right part, and when we press the Enter button, it don't execute the command, but go to a new line (that start with '>' if I well remember).
When we are done, we press the second shortcut, and it paste the part that where deleted before, and the Enter key behavior come back as the original.

(I tought it was something like Ctrl+j / ctrl+f, but it's not, I also tried many combination but never succeed)

Hoping you remember them, you'll make my day. Thanks!

### Edit for a better understanding:

On a command like this (a call to a ros service, providing arguments):

```
rosservice call /operatorshift/updateProgramSteps "category: ''
name: ''
steps:
- command: ''
  args: ''
othersarg ''"
```

The steps argument is an array, and I want to provide more than one step, without deleting and rewriting the next lines.
The behavior is as follow:
I move my cursor at the end of the 5th line (args: '' [HERE]), and I press the first shortcut. The command would look like:

```
rosservice call /operatorshift/updateProgramSteps "category: ''
name: ''
steps:
- command: ''
  args: ''
```

and I press "enter", not to execute the command, but to add a new line (and the '>' character appear on the left of my cursor, instead of my computer's name). I can write my other "step", pressing "enter" many time if I want, so my terminal would look like this:

```
rosservice call /operatorshift/updateProgramSteps "category: ''
name: ''
steps:
- command: ''
  args: ''  
> - command: 'example'
> args: ''
>
```

Then I'm done editing this command, so I press the second shortcut, that retrieve what the first have deleted, and the "enter" key get its default behavior (execute the command)

```
rosservice call /operatorshift/updateProgramSteps "category: ''
name: ''
steps:
- command: ''
  args: ''  
> - command: 'example'
> args: ''
othersarg ''"
```

(not sure that '>' stay on screen after pressing the second shortcut)

I remember using it on Ubuntu 14.04, and on 16.04, with the default shell, without having to install a special package.

Comment: What shell do you use ?
With `zsh` you can use Alt+Enter or ESC+Enter to add a newline.

Comment: I use bash, as it's the default shell on ubuntu, but thank for the tip !

Comment: @MatEhickey Did you get the answer ? ESC+Enter or Alt+Enter is anyone working for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, I think the easiest solution is to use bash's edit-and-execute-command feature; from the manual:

> edit-and-execute-command (C-xC-e)
>
> Invoke an editor on the current command line, and execute the result as shell commands.  Bash attempts to invoke $VISUAL, $EDITOR, and emacs as the editor, in that order.

if you use bash in vi mode, you can invoke it by simply pressing `v` in normal mode.

This will open your command in your editor set up by `$VISUAL` or `$EDITOR` environmental variables.

Comment: Hello, this is actually a really good workaround ! Not the exact thing I remember tho (wasn't opening a editor, but editing it in the current terminal, keeping the history in screen). The difference is very minor, so I think this answer might be the closest call on this one ! Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

Just type "\", and when you press enter the ">" symbol you mentioned will appear

Comment: That's only when at the end of the command, the behavior I described precised that it's applicable on the middle of a command.

Comment: for exemple, I want to append some "- 0" in this command, without removing myself the rest:     rosservice call /operatorshift/addPlane "category: 'a'
program: 'abk'
plane:
  name: 'plan2'
  point1:
  - 0            
  point2:
  - 0
  point3:
  - 0"      (can't I use newlines on stackoverflow comments ? ... )

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not understanding your question. Can you please write how you would like that command to look? Just write something like **[ENTER]** in the places you wanted a new line.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be [heredoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) ?

```
$ cat << EOF
> \$ Working dir "$PWD" `pwd`
> EOF
$ Working dir "/home/user" /home/user
```

Comment: It might be a solution for writing a huge command, but I don't know how it could be use for editing an existing one (without manually copy/pasting). BTW I didn't know that, and it could be useful in many cases, thank you !

Comment: what exactly you are looking for?